# What exactly is the SELECT clause used for in SQL

Tags: sql, select

As a beginner of SQL, I observed that the FROM clause typically contains only the address of the data table, but the SELECT clause seem to be a different scenario. Is it safe to put up the hat that the `SELECT` clause is the actual verb i.e. the actual action to be taken in the whole command, since it displays all the columns required in the syntax?

Comment: **SELECT** column1, column2, column3 **FROM** table1  
SELECT is basically to get exactly the columns you're looking for from a specific table, sometimes you need all the columns , you write SELECT * FROM table1,  and if you want for example the first_name, last_name, age you need to write    

**SELECT** *first_name*, *last_name*, *age* **FROM** *table*

Comment: Yes, `Select` , `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete` can be seen as _"actual verbs"_ in SQL

Comment: Select is the statement wich is last executed from a sql query. It creates the result view from previously generated result.